# Vue hide a table's component button on a specific page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a table as a component that loads on some pages. In the table there is a button to create goals. But as I use this table on different pages, there are pages that I don't want this add goals button to be loaded, but on other pages this button will be loaded. Below I'm putting the table component and a page that I wouldn't want to load that button on it.

employeePage

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto overflow-hidden" height="900" width="1800">
    <div class="content">
      <MetasTableComponent
        :title="'Global Goal'"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="globalGoals"
        :loading="loadingGobalGoals"
      />
      <MetasTableComponent
        :title="'Sectorial Goals'"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="sectorialGoals"
        :loading="loadingMetasSetoriais"
      />
      <MetasTableComponent
        :title="'Individual Goals'"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="individualGoals"
        :loading="loadingMetasIndividuais"
        @save-data="createIndividualGoal"
      />
    </div>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
import {
  findGlobalGoals,
  findSectorialGoals,
  findIndividualGoals,  
  createIndividualGoal,
} from "...";
import MetasTableComponent from "...";

export default {
  name: "IndividualViewPage",
  components: {
    MetasTableComponent,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      group: null,
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Name",
          value: "GoalName",
          align: "left",
          width: 50,
          caption: "title",
        },
        {
          text: "Min",
          value: "Min",
          align: "left",
          width: 50,
          caption: "title",
        },
        {
          text: "Target",
          value: "Target",
          align: "left",
          width: 50,
          caption: "title",
        },
        {
          text: "Max",
          value: "Max",
          align: "left",
          width: 50,
          caption: "title",
        },
        {
          text: "Result",
          value: "Result",
          align: "left",
          width: 50,
          caption: "title",
        },
        {
          text: "Actions",
          value: "actions",
          align: "left",
          width: 40,
          caption: "title",
        },
      ],
      globalGoals: [],
      sectorialGoals: [],
      individualGoals: [],
      loadGlobalGoals: false,
      loadSectorialGoals: false,
      loadingIndividualGoals: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async createIndividualGoal(data) {
      [...]
    },
    async loadGlobalGoals() {
      [...]
    },
    async loadSectorialGoals() {
      [...]
    },
    async loadIndividualGoals() {
      [...]
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadGlobalGoals();
    this.loadSectorialGoals();
    this.loadIndividualGoals();
  },
};
</script>
```

Table component

```
<template>
  <div id="table">
    <v-card class="mx-auto mb-3">
      <v-app-bar dark color="green">
        <v-toolbar-title>{{ title }}</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-app-bar>

      <v-data-table
        dense
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        item-key="name"
        class="elevation-1"
        :loading="loading"
        loading-text="Loading..."
        no-data-text="No record found."
        :items-per-page="20"
        :footer-props="{
          itemsPerPageText: 'Items por page',
          itemsPerPageAllText: 'All',
        }"
      >
        <template v-slot:top>
          <v-toolbar flat color="white">
            <v-row dense>
              <v-col cols="1">
                <v-btn
                  class="mx-5 mt-2"
                  fab
                  x-small
                  dark
                  color="green"
                  @click="createData()" //This is the button that add goal
                >
                  <v-icon dark>mdi-plus</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-toolbar>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
          <v-tooltip right>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-icon
                small
                class="ml-1"
                @click="readData(item)"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                >mdi-eye</v-icon
              >
            </template>
            <span>View</span>
          </v-tooltip>

          <v-tooltip right>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-icon
                small
                class="ml-1"
                @click="updateData(item)"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                >mdi-pencil</v-icon
              >
            </template>
            <span>Editar</span>
          </v-tooltip>

          <v-tooltip right>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
              <v-icon
                small
                class="ml-1"
                @click="deleteData(item)"
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
                >mdi-delete</v-icon
              >
            </template>
            <span>Delete</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-card>

    <v-dialog v-model="formDialog">
    <v-card ref="form">
      <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2">
        {{ formDialogTitle }}
      </v-card-title>

      <v-card-text>
        <v-row dense class="mt-5">
          <v-col cols="4">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="itemData.GoalName"
              label="Name"
              dense
              counter="150"
              maxlength="150"
              :readonly="isReading"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="itemData.Min"
              label="Min"
              dense
              counter="150"
              maxlength="150"
              :readonly="isReading"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="itemData.Max"
              label="Max"
              dense
              counter="150"
              maxlength="150"
              :readonly="isReading"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="itemData.Target"
              label="Target"
              dense
              counter="150"
              maxlength="150"
              :readonly="isReading"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="2">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="itemData.Result"
              label="Result"
              dense
              counter="150"
              maxlength="150"
              :readonly="isReading"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>

        </v-row>
      </v-card-text>

      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn color="red" dark small @click="formDialog = false">
          Close
        </v-btn>

        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn small color="primary" v-if="!isReading" @click="saveData()"
          >Save
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {

} from "../services/goals-service/crud-goals-service";

export default {
  props: {
    title: { type: String },
    headers: { type: Array },
    items: { type: Array },
    loading: { type: Boolean },
    functionCallback: { type: Function },
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      formDialog: false,
      formDialogTitle: "",
      itemData: {},
      isCreating: false,
      isReading: false,
      isUpdating: false,
      isDeleting: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {   
    createData() {
      this.itemData = {};
      this.formDialogTitle = `${this.title}: New Goal`;
      this.isCreating = true;
      this.isReading = false;
      this.isUpdating = false;
      this.isDeleting = false;
      this.formDialog = true;
    },
    readData(item) {
      this.itemData = item;
      this.formDialogTitle = `${this.title}: ${item.GoalName}`;
      this.formDialog = true;
      this.isReading = true;
      this.isCreating = false;
      this.isUpdating = false;
      this.isDeleting = false;
    },
    updateData(item) {
      console.log('updateData', item);
    },
    deleteData(item) {
      console.log('deleteData', item);
    },
    async saveData() {
      this.$emit('save-data', this.itemData);
  }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one more Props in Table component called "EnableGoalAction" boolean value

pass this value true/false from your component implemented page based on your need.

you need check if condition in your button like below

```
     <v-btn
              class="mx-5 mt-2"
              fab
              x-small
              dark
              color="green"
             v-if="EnableGoalAction"
              @click="createData()" //This is the button that add goal
            >
              <v-icon dark>mdi-plus</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
```

Comment: I was a little confused on some issues. In Componet I will create the EnableGoalAction function as true and false (would you use VueRouter to check ?) depending on the page or will the implementation of this method be in employee page?

Comment: I understand your solution, but it ends up hiding for all tables: Global, Sectorial and Individual. I just want to hide from the global and sectoral

Comment: I achieved! Thank you very much